# php api rewrite not working XAMPP going to dashboard

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, php-7.3

I'm running `XAMPP` and am trying to catch all requests to my `Directory`

`http://localhost/api` works and serves `index.php` in the `api`-folder

I don't know if the rewrite is working at all since all requests to `http://localhost/api/whatever` ends up at `http://localhost/dashboard`

**httpd.conf**

```
Alias /api "F:/src/api"

<Directory "F:/src/api">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**.htaccess** (in my `F:\src\api` folder)

As far as I know this should redirect all requests to `index.php` but it doesn't

```
Options -MultiViews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L,NC,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

How can I get my rewrite to work?

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` is checking if the file doesn't exist .. Is that what you're trying to do?  Because this will only redirect if it gets a 404 error --   If you want ALL files and directories .. Then lose the `!`

Comment: @Zak yes, I want to do that. If the file exists, it should pick that one and not redirect. Like the index.php file

Comment: With that said, I don't see an issue with your `.htaccess`  --  However, wouldn't it better suit though to have just one line? --> `ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/api/index.php` ??  =  Everything not found, goes to index.php

Comment: @Zak I figured it out. It should be `RewriteRule . /api/index.php [L,NC,QSA]`. The redirect was working but directed to `/index.php`

Comment: @Zak perhaps the `ErrorDocument` also works

Comment: Since you have access to your http servers host configuration stop using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those come with a ton of disadvantages.

Comment: @arkascha On my dev machine I do, on prod I don't...? Any other alternative?